# How to update react useState without delay?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

When I call `fetchProducts` I want productPage state to be updated before it runs the next line of code since the next line requires the updated state.

The state only gets updated after the function has finished running. No matter where in the `fetchProducts` function I put `console.log(productPage)` it returns the state as it was before the function was called.

```
   const [productPage, setProductPage] = useState(1)
   const [displayProducts, setDisplayProducts] = useState([])

   const fetchProducts = async () => {

      setProductPage(productPage + 1) // DOES NOT UPDATE UNTIL AFTER FUNCTION RUNS

      const newProductsData = await fetch(`/api/getproducts?page=${productPage}`)
      const newProductsArr = await newProductsData.json()
      setDisplayProducts(displayProducts.concat(newProductsArr))

   }
```

Is this possible? I've found workarounds to the problem but it feels hacky and not ideal.

I'm using next.js also, I'm not sure if that would make a difference. I can't use normal variables as they reset on each render.

Comment: Store productPage + 1 in a const at top of function and just use that var instead? Do the tasks you want to perform within the scope of the function and set the state when you are finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setProductPage` will update the state and trigger a new render. `productPage` is not the state, it's just a variable holding the value of the state the moment you used useState. It will never change, it will always have the same value. You think it changes, but in reality, the function is simply executed again, but now `productPage` assigned with the new value.

So what can you do? You have two options.

The one it use useEffect, that will see if `productPage` changes (every time the function is executed = re-renders), and if it is, it will fetch the data and use `setDisplayProducts` to re-render the component with a new value in `displayProducts`. This is nice if you plan to have other ways of updating the productPage and you want them to also trigger the fetch.

```
const [productPage, setProductPage] = useState(1)
const [displayProducts, setDisplayProducts] = useState([])

const fetchProducts = async () => {
   setProductPage(productPage + 1);
}

useEffect(() => {
    const getDisplayProducts = async () => {
        const newProductsData = await fetch(`/api/getproducts?page=${productPage}`)
        const newProductsArr = await newProductsData.json()
        setDisplayProducts(displayProducts.concat(newProductsArr))
    };

    getDisplayProducts();
}, [productPage]);
```

The second one is just store the new value in a variable, pass the variable to the `setProductPage` but use the variable in the fetch and not `productPage`.

```
const [productPage, setProductPage] = useState(1)
const [displayProducts, setDisplayProducts] = useState([])

const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const nextProductPage = productPage + 1;

    setProductPage(nextProductPage);
    const newProductsData = await fetch(`/api/getproducts?page=${nextProductPage}`)
    const newProductsArr = await newProductsData.json()
    setDisplayProducts(displayProducts.concat(newProductsArr));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of how the useState hook works. useEffect hook was one of the solutions I'd tried but was hoping for a more concise, cleaner solution. Looks like I have no choice though. Thaks for the help!

Comment: I wish setState and and dispatch (from useReducer) functions would return the new state.

Comment: Yeah, that would be nice and allow for more concise code.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a state is an async operation and you can't use it like a sync operation.

So, you must use **useEffect** hook, which runs after state changes.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const [productPage, setProductPage] = useState(1)
const [displayProducts, setDisplayProducts] = useState([])

const fetchProducts = async () => {
   setProductPage(productPage + 1)
}

useEffect(() => {
   const newProductsData = await fetch(`/api/getproducts?page=${productPage}`)
   const newProductsArr = await newProductsData.json()
   setDisplayProducts(displayProducts.concat(newProductsArr))
}, [productPage]); // <-- monitor productPage for changes
```